# How to extend Apple provisioning profiles?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

Have a sample application running on an iPhone. 
The provision profile will be expired soon. Wish to ask if the provision can be extended. 
Hope that somebody knowledgeable in this area can help.

Comment: Consider following the App Store proposal on Area 51.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you can do is renew the provision profile and install it on the device.

Comment: I am currently away from my workplace and have no access to my Mac mini for the moment. Can I just do the renewal request on my iPhone alone?

Comment: Sort of. You can renew it but you can't install it.

Comment: I have always done it thru Xcode.  But you try the iOS Dev Center. But you still have the issue of getting it onto the device.

Comment: now I am back from my trip home and is in front of my apple computer.  Have log into apple's dev center and tried to extend the provision. As mentioned in SO question 1342497, there is a renew button but it would not appear until the provision is expired.  I cannot find the renew button either.  Tried what others have done - edit the provision, submit again, download a new provision file and drag it to the device icon.  The expiratory date suddenly disappeared.  Although I don't have a new expiratory date, hope that its disappearance indicates something positive ...